# Play an mp3 file in a subfolder via mcisendstring

Tags: c++, mp3, mcisendstring

### make mcisendstring to play a file in subdirectory

I have a little problem with mcisendstring. I know you can open a text file in a subdirectory like this:

```
ofstream file(".\\subfolder\\file.txt");
```

**but in mcisendstring that doesn't work**
I have the exe file in a folder called main and the music in a subfolder called music. It would be .\\music\\song.mp3 but that doesn't work
visual studio won't let me create a subfolder for resources. What do I do?

Comment: When running from from inside the Visual Studio IDE, the current directory is the project root directory and not where the executable is located. Make sure that you're using the right relative path to the files, or use absolute paths.

Comment: "doesn't work" = ? What is the error code?

Comment: but i can't create a resource in a subfolder like "main folder/music"? the error is 275

Comment: so after i listened to RTO i figured it out: L"open .\\music\\song.mp3 type MPEGvideo alias song", NULL, 0, 0); thanks for the help